# How to plot 3 or more values in plot.bar()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to make plot.bar() using 2 values having them in a list, but I'm unable to plot 3 values.

I tried to add plot.bar(x,y,z), but it didn't work.

```py
ce_data = ce_data.drop(
            ['pchangeinOpenInterest', 'totalTradedVolume', 'impliedVolatility',  # this removes unecesssary items
             'pChange', 'totalBuyQuantity', 'totalSellQuantity', 'bidQty',
             'bidprice', 'askQty', 'askPrice', 'askQty', 'identifier', 'lastPrice', 'change', 'expiryDate',
             'underlying'], axis=1)[
            ['openInterest', 'changeinOpenInterest', 'strikePrice', 'underlyingValue']]

        style.use('ggplot')
        ce_data.to_csv('kumar.csv')

        df = pd.read_csv('kumar.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
        pivot = df.iloc[2, 3]  # this selects the strike price
        pivot_round = round(pivot, -2)  # round of the price

x = df['strikePrice'].tolist()
y = df['changeinOpenInterest'].tolist()
z = df['openInterest'].tolist()

for i in range(len(x)):
    if int(x[i]) >= pivot_round - 400:
        xleftpos = i
        break

for i in range(len(x)):
    if int(x[i]) >= pivot_round + 400:
        xrightpos = i
        break

x = x[xleftpos:xrightpos]
y = y[xleftpos:xrightpos]
z = z[xleftpos:xrightpos]

plot.bar([value for value in range(len(x))],y)

plot.set_xticks([idx + 0.5 for idx in range(len(x))])
plot.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=35, ha='right', size=10)
```

I am expecting strike price in x axis and y and z (change in oi and oi) in as bars.

Comment: Since we don't know what is *in* your `df` and it isn't really relevant to the question - can you provide a minimal example of the `x`, `y`,and `z` that you are trying to plot (just after the slice)??

Comment: As in you want a 3D chart? Or you want the x and y grouped by z?

Comment: like need x in x axis , y and z as bar in 2D , added df code too @wwii

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here's how I'd do it. This should have a single x-axis w/ 'strikePrice' and two bars of 'changeinOpenInterest' and 'openInterest'.

```
disp_df = df.pivot('strikePrice', 'changeinOpenInterest', 'openInterest')
disp_df.plot(kind='bar')
```

You can add the bells and whistles you want to the plot, but this avoids a lot of the manipulation you did above.

Comment: what to do with pivot , i set it to get the price range square off

Comment: Do you want a chart that shows open interest and ch in open interest as bars against strike? If not, please explain what output you are actually looking to achieve.

Comment: Yes... I needed the same, but how can pivot be added to data frame ?

Comment: My code above basically creates a new dataframe just for display purposes and keeps the original dataframe intact